# Dynamically expandable table view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, customization

I'm trying to implement an expandable table view cells.Like headers and sub-header views.
On selecting the cell, it expands with few more cells with json data that is being parsed.
The data to be populated is received from a JSON object.
Can any one help me with this?

Comment: here you can do it easily in swift https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RKeVv0I3jnA

Answer (score 0):

you can use `uitableview` methods

```
[UITableview beginUpdates];

// delete the row in table view 

 [UITableview deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1 inSection:lastcount - 1]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];

// insert section in table Or Set as per your need

[UITableview insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:NSMakeRange(Array.count - [[results objectForKey:@"data"] count], [[results objectForKey:@"data"] count])] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

[UITableview endUpdates];
```

Hope it will work for you .

Answer (score 0):

Create your categories as section headers and your subcategories as rows of a specific section. Use this UITableView delegate methods:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // calculate section count == number of categories

    return sectionCount;
}

-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // create section header for section...
    // add a button so you can monitor if user tapped on section and
    // set button's tag = section
    // configure section view
    return vwSectionHeader;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // if section not tapped than numberOfSubcategoriesForASection = 0
    // else 
    // calcualate numberOfSubcategoriesForASection

    return numberOfSubcategoriesForASection;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // dequeue your cell that corespondes to the subcategory
    // configure cell
    return cell;
}

-(void)BtnSectionPressed:(id)sender{
    // update data source subcategories for selected section
    // section == [sender tag]
    // [reload table]
    // or nicer solution
    [UITableview beginUpdates];
    // colapse previous section
    // call with array of subcategories index paths for section last expanded
    - (void)deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray<NSIndexPath *> *)indexPaths withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation;
    // expand new section
    // call with array of subcategories index paths for section you want to expand
    - (void)insertRowsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray<NSIndexPath *> *)indexPaths withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation
    [UITableview endUpdates];
}
```